# Downloading PDF file in iOS from a webview in Flutter

Tags: flutter, wkwebview, flutterwebviewplugin, flutter-inappwebview

I'm using **flutter_inappwebview** as my main plugin to launch the URL in the webview.
I decided to use this specific plugin because it allows the navigationGestures in iOS devices.

Certainly, I'm facing a problem that my website does contains a page where there are multiple download buttons for downloading the pdf files. When those buttons are clicked, a quick viewer is opening which do not have any back button, share button, or anything by default. I want to download those pdf files into my iOS device's storage.

I've tried using the **flutter_downloader** package but that too isn't working for me.
Below is the code which shows the implementation of the webview.

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
        child: WillPopScope(
            onWillPop: () async {
              if (await _webViewController!.canGoBack()) {
                _webViewController!.goBack();
                return false;
              }
              return true;
            },
          child: InAppWebView(
            initialUrlRequest: URLRequest(
              url: Uri.parse(initialUrl),
              headers: {
                'Content-Security-Policy': 'default-src \'self\';',
                'X-content-type-options': 'nosniff'
              }
            ),
            initialOptions: InAppWebViewGroupOptions(
              crossPlatform: InAppWebViewOptions(
                javaScriptEnabled: true,
                cacheEnabled: true,
                useOnDownloadStart: true,
              ),
              ios: IOSInAppWebViewOptions(
                allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures: true,
                disableLongPressContextMenuOnLinks: true,
              )
            ),
            onWebViewCreated: (controller) {
              _webViewController = controller;
              HTTPCookieSameSitePolicy.STRICT;
            },
            onLoadStop: (controller, url) async {
              if (url!.path.contains('.pdf')) {
                final directory = await getExternalStorageDirectory();
                final taskId = await FlutterDownloader.enqueue(
                    url: url.toString(),
                    savedDir: directory!.path,
                    showNotification: true,
                    openFileFromNotification: true,
                );
                print(taskId);
              }
            },
          ),
        ),
    );
  }
```

In the onLoadStop function, I have also tried `if (url.toString().contains('pdf')` but this is not working as well.

And instead of downloading the file, I also tried to redirect the link to the external browser using **url_launcher** package but that is also not working in my case.